# JavaFX TableView selected cell

Tags: javafx, tableview

There is tableview with 3 columns

```
id   | stack     | amount
 1   | Древесина | 5
```

I need minus 1 from the value of the cell(amount) by pressing the button.

```
 ObservableList<ModelTable> oblist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

 @Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

//DB

    try {
        Connection con = DBConn.getConnection();
        ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from piles");
        while (rs.next()) {
            oblist.add(new ModelTable(rs.getString("num_pile"), rs.getString("gruz"), rs.getInt("amount")));
        }
    }catch (SQLException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

col_id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
col_pile.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("pile"));
col_amount.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("amount"));

table.setItems(oblist);

buttonAdd.setOnAction(e -> {

    ModelTable selectedItem = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    //minus 1 of cell value




});
```

My english is not perfect. I hope you understood. Thanks!

Comment: Depends on the `ModelTable` class. It's significantly simpler if the class contains a `amountProperty` method retuning a `IntegerProperty` object...

Comment: Amount is an Integer

Comment: First `selectedItem.setAmount(selectedItem.getAmount() - 1)`. Then place `selectedItem` back into `table` overwrting the object at the selected index.

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.